# Jquery: Hide child <div> when user clicks inside parent <div>

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and would like to hide a DIV when the user clicks anywhere inside it's parent DIV. If the user clicks outside of the parent DIV then nothing would happen.

```
<div id="BodyField">
    <div class="video-field-new"></div>
</div>
```

So I would like the DIV with "video-field-new" to hide when user clicks inside of #BodyField.

**Background**: I have a small banner that lays over a video in the corner when the video is new, but I do not want it to block the video player when the user plays the video. So ideally when the user clicks to play the video, which is inside the #BodyField then the banner will hide.

Comment: $("#BodyField").click(function(){$(this).children("div").hide()}

Comment: @gaurav That'll cause **every** child `div` element to be hidden.

Comment: Right but what if he gives many divs the same class name?

Comment: See my answer. It's better to use `$(this).children('selector')`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#BodyField').on('click', function() {  
    $(this).children('.video-field-new').hide();
});
```

You will also need to prevent the click event from the `.video-field-new` from propagating up to its parent, otherwise clicking the video to play will cause itself to be hidden.

```
$('#BodyField .video-field-new').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: when I add the above I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using an old version of jQuery by the sounds it. Either use `live()` instead, or update jQuery (better solution).

Comment: Great! That worked, but one problem. The ribbon is on a Vimeo Video which is in an iFrame and it wont disappear when clicking on the iframe. Can that be helped?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because `iframe` elements don't register the `click` event.

Comment: bummer! I will try to see if I can trick it with putting a transparent div over the play button. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".video-field-new:parent").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".video-field-new").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#BodyField").click(function(){ $(".video-field-new").hide(); });
```